# grounding rod concrete

Tags: electrical, grounding, code-compliance

Is it Ok to cover over a grounding rod in concrete? I have two grounding rods one is right by the meter socket and the other one is about 6 feet away. I am having a concrete patio and wanted to know if the concrete can cover the grounding rods?

Comment: Whether code allows this or not (I suspect not) someone who's more familiar with code will certainly chime in.  But regardless, it's a bad idea since you will no longer be able to inspect or service the grounding rod.  I'd put a short piece of PVC pipe around it to serve as a form and leave it open.

Comment: And run pvc over the cable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many local jurisdictions have amendments to the NEC that require ground rod and Ufer ground connections remain accessible.

NEC 250.68 ex.1 allows concrete encased connections to grounding electrodes to not remain accessible, 250.70 specifies the clamps need to be *Listed* for concrete. Such as [T&B Blackburn Type JWR](https://www.ideadigitalcontent.com/files/NEURBRO/103195.pdf), page 79. (I don't really know the manufacturing difference those *Listed* and not.)

Comment: That being said considering potential for concealed damage or doing that type of work without having a permit or inspection report showing cover approval I would consider relocating the ground rods.